# Can't select the default value in <select> React Event Handlers

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-forms

So I don't know if this is a bug or something I did wrong but when I try to submit the default value of  browser doesn't alert the value of <select*> which is 'react'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class Form extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
         topic:'',
    }
}

handleTopicChange = event => {
    this.setState({topic: event.target.value,})}

handleSubmit = event => {
    alert(`${this.state.topic}`)
}

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <label>Topic</label>
            <select value={this.state.topic} onChange={this.handleTopicChange}>
                <option value="react">React</option>
                <option value="vue">Vue</option>
                <option value="angular">Angular</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the normal behavior because you set default value is empty but you don't specify the `<option value="" />` tag with empty value which means browser will select the 1st item as selected item. In order to be make more sense, you should add that empty option as yet selected:

```js
<option value="react">React</option>
<option value="vue">Vue</option>
<option value="angular">Angular</option>
<option value="">---</option>
```

Then browser will select empty option `---` as default.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.state = { topic: '' }` to `this.state = { topic: 'react' }` so the entire code should be:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class Form extends Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state =  {
        topic: 'react',
   }
}


handleTopicChange = event => {
   this.setState({topic: event.target.value,})}

handleSubmit = event => {
   alert(`${this.state.topic}`)
}

render() {
   return (
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <div>
           <label>Topic</label>
           <select value={this.state.topic} onChange={this.handleTopicChange}>
               <option value="react">React</option>
               <option value="vue">Vue</option>
               <option value="angular">Angular</option>
           </select>
       </div>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
   )
}} 
export default Form
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is annoying and the way selection boxes work is like that as in the default value is always empty "" and you want your users to select a value.

BUT if I had to do it, I think the cleanest way is to use React's `useState` and encapsulate the component.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState("React");  // set default value here
  
  const handleSelection = (e) => {
    const selectionValue = e.target.value
    console.log(selectionValue);
    setSelection(selectionValue); // set current state
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* show current state in below div */}
      <h1>Selected Topic: {selection}</h1>
      <select onChange={handleSelection} defaultValue="React">
        <option value="React">React</option>
        <option value="Vue">Vue</option>
        <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```